'invalid account data' error when using Immutable Owner extension and Non-transferable extensions together
Following guides, https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/non-transferable#build-instructions and https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/immutable-owner#conclusion
They can work well separately. However, if I put them together, immutable-owner always shows
Error processing Instruction 2: invalid account data for instruction.

My code is based on guide.
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
 import {Program, web3} from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Sol } from "../target/types/sol";
import {it} from "mocha";
import {Connection, Keypair, sendAndConfirmTransaction, SystemProgram, Transaction} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
AuthorityType,
createInitializeAccountInstruction,
createInitializeImmutableOwnerInstruction,
createInitializeMintInstruction,
createInitializeNonTransferableMintInstruction,
createMint,
ExtensionType,
getAccountLen, getMintLen, setAuthority,
TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
} from "@solana/spl-token";
import {min} from "bn.js";

//anchor test
describe("sol", () => {
// Configure the client to use the local cluster.
anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());

const program = anchor.workspace.Sol as Program<Sol>;
const Seed = anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode("conf");

let adminPubKey;

before( async () => {
    [adminPubKey] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
        [Seed, anchor.AnchorProvider.env().wallet.publicKey.toBytes()],
        program.programId
    );
});
it( "Is createAdmin", async () => {
    const payer = web3.Keypair.generate();

// Connection to devnet cluster
    const connection = new Connection('http://127.0.0.1:8899', 'confirmed');

 // Transaction signature returned from sent transaction
    let transactionSignature: string;

    const airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
        payer.publicKey,
        web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, // 1 SOL
    );
    await connection.confirmTransaction(airdropSignature);
    const balanceA = await connection.getBalance(payer.publicKey)
    console.log("airdropSignature success", balanceA);


    // Authority that can mint new tokens
    const mintAuthority = payer.publicKey;
   // Decimals for Mint Account
    const decimals = 2;



    

    const mintLen = getMintLen([ExtensionType.NonTransferable]);
  // Minimum lamports required for Mint Account
    let lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(mintLen);

    const mintKeypair = Keypair.generate();
 // Address for Mint Account
    const mint = mintKeypair.publicKey;

    const createAccountInstructionA = SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: payer.publicKey, // Account that will transfer lamports to created account
        newAccountPubkey: mint, // Address of the account to create
        space: mintLen, // Amount of bytes to allocate to the created account
        lamports, // Amount of lamports transferred to created account
        programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Program assigned as owner of created account
    });
    console.log("createAccountInstruction",createAccountInstructionA)

  // Instruction to initialize the NonTransferable Extension
    const initializeNonTransferableMintInstructionA =
        createInitializeNonTransferableMintInstruction(
            mint, // Mint Account address
            TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program ID
        );
    



    // Instruction to initialize Mint Account data
    const initializeMintInstructionA = createInitializeMintInstruction(
        mint, // Mint Account Address
        decimals, // Decimals of Mint
        anchor.AnchorProvider.env().publicKey, // Designated Mint Authority
        null, // Optional Freeze Authority
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program ID
    );
    console.log("initializeMintInstruction",initializeMintInstructionA)
    // Add instructions to new transaction
    const transactionA = new Transaction().add(
        createAccountInstructionA,
        initializeNonTransferableMintInstructionA,
        initializeMintInstructionA,
    );
    console.log("mint:",mint)

    // Send transaction
    transactionSignature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
        connection,
        transactionA,
        [payer, mintKeypair], // Signers
    );

    console.log(
        "transactionSignature",transactionSignature
    )








    // Random keypair to use as owner of Token Account
    const tokenAccountKeypair = Keypair.generate();
    // Address for Token Account
    const tokenAccount = tokenAccountKeypair.publicKey;

    // Size of Token Account with extension
    const accountLen = getAccountLen([ExtensionType.ImmutableOwner]);
    // Minimum lamports required for Token Account
     lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(accountLen);


    // Instruction to invoke System Program to create new account
    const createAccountInstruction = SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: payer.publicKey, // Account that will transfer lamports to created account
        newAccountPubkey: tokenAccount, // Address of the account to create
        space: accountLen, // Amount of bytes to allocate to the created account
        lamports, // Amount of lamports transferred to created account
        programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Program assigned as owner of created account
    });

    // Instruction to initialize the ImmutableOwner Extension
    const initializeImmutableOwnerInstruction =
        createInitializeImmutableOwnerInstruction(
            tokenAccount, // Token Account address
            TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program ID
        );

    // Instruction to initialize Token Account data
    const initializeAccountInstruction = createInitializeAccountInstruction(
        tokenAccount, // Token Account Address
        mint, // Mint Account
        payer.publicKey, // Token Account Owner
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program ID
    );
    console.log("mint:",mint)

    // Add instructions to new transaction
    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
        createAccountInstruction,
       // initializeImmutableOwnerInstruction,
        initializeAccountInstruction,
    );

   // Send transaction
    transactionSignature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
        connection,
        transaction,
        [payer, tokenAccountKeypair], // Signers
    );

    console.log(
        "\nCreate Token Account:",
        `https://solana.fm/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=devnet-solana`,
    );




    


})





});


The provided account length won't be enough, because you also need to include space for the NonTransferableAccount extension. I think it should work if you just change the line creating accountLen to:
    const accountLen = getAccountLen([ExtensionType.ImmutableOwner, ExtensionType.NonTransferableAccount]);

You can start by running the end-to-end tests for the non-transferable extension at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/646efc13449fa6e1a8f69d767283478d2a0002e4/token/js/test/e2e-2022/nonTransferableMint.test.ts#L54
